# Adding source files and updating dependencies in makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm writing a (dynamic) library in C++, and have a set of tests for it. Currently, I'm working a makefile (default target) that can either build the library or build and run the tests (`test` target). The whole difference is in a couple of linker flags and whether or not a single `.cpp` file (containing `main`) is included, but I can't get the `test` target to build properly, since the dependency list does not get updated for some reason.
Here's the whole makefile:

```
CXX = g++
RM=rm -f

EXTRA_CCFLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra -Wcast-qual -Wfloat-equal -Wpedantic -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow
CXXOPTFLAGS     = -O2
CXXFLAGS        = -std=c++11 $(EXTRA_CCFLAGS) $(CXXOPTFLAGS)

LDLIBS=-larmadillo
MAKELIBFLAGS=-current_version 0.1 -compatibility_version 0.1 -dynamiclib

TARGET = libadsp.dylib
TESTTARGET = dsptest
SOURCE_FILES=src/stft.cpp src/filters.cpp src/windows.cpp src/helpers.cpp
OBJECT_FILES=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCE_FILES))

all: $(TARGET)

test: SOURCE_FILES += tests/tests.cpp
test: OBJECT_FILES = $(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCE_FILES))
test: $(TESTTARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(MAKELIBFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(LDLIBS)

$(TESTTARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TESTTARGET) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(LDLIBS)
    ./dsptest

depend: .depend

.depend: $(SOURCE_FILES)
    $(RM) ./.depend
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM $^>>./.depend;

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(RM) ./.depend

include .depend
```

Comment: Typically `make` is used to _make_ things, not run things (I'm not a fan of side effects of make).   That being said, you want to be able to make your test or your regular build.    One note: you're always rebuilding your `.depend` file no matter what.  If this was a large project this would kill your build time.   A better practice is to have a target-specific objects directory, and then generate .d files in there for each source as you're compiling them.   This link: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/] has a good description.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use target-specific variable values in prerequisite lists.  The GNU make manual is [very clear](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) about this:

> The other exception is target-specific variable values. This feature allows you to define different values for the same variable, based on the target that make is currently building. **As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).**

(emphasis added).  You can add the test target specifically:

```
$(TESTTARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES) tests/tests.o
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
        ./dsptest
```

PS. I don't recommend using `$(subst ...)` to replace extensions; use `$(patsubst ...)` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, this solution requires that `OBJECT_FILES` still be modified as a target-specific variable. (And I'd be in favor of changing that, for the sake of clarity.)

Comment: You're right, that was my bad.  Fixed to use automatic variables which is more correct anyway: with this you can avoid making OBJECT_FILES a target-specific variable.